# cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'filter-regex'

Tags: xml, spring-mvc, applicationcontext

When editing applicationContext.xml in eclipse, the following content

```
<bean name="data-bus"  class="XXX.mvp.databus.OnlineClassDatabusConfiguration">
    <filter-regex>vip_oc.online_class, vip.student</filter-regex>
    <poll-timeout>300</poll-timeout>
    <auto-offset-reset-config>earliest</auto-offset-reset-config>
    <group-id>test</group-id>s
    <topic-test1>vip_oc</topic-test1>
    <topic-test2>vip</topic-test2>
    <bootstrap-servers>127.0.0.1:9092</bootstrap-servers>
    <max-poll-records>300</max-poll-records>
</bean>
```

raises the error:

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'filter-regex'. One of '{"http://
>    www.springframework.org/schema/beans":description, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/
>    beans":meta, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":constructor-arg, "http://
>    www.springframework.org/schema/beans":property, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/
>    beans":qualifier, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":lookup-method, "http://
>    www.springframework.org/schema/beans":replaced-method, WC[##other:"http://
>    www.springframework.org/schema/beans"]}' is expected.

I googled the error, and some places says the order does the matter.. I  tried re-arrange the item inside the bean, but the error is still there.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The content model defined in the schema for the `<bean>` element appears to be completely unrelated to the content you are trying to produce. This suggests something is grossly wrong: you've configured Eclipse to validate with the wrong schema, you're using the wrong namespace, or something like that.